# How can I print it out in order?

Tags: java

I use object and override, but I don't like the printed result

The result I want is...

```
ex)
1: Salaried object creation, 2: Hour object creation 3. Exit --> 1

name, id number, monthly salary : 

A 2345 3000000



How do I fix the code?
```

Answer (score 1):

### Problem

You are not assigning the `SalariedEmployee` and `HourEmployee` objects to your `Person[]`.

### Solution

Create a counter variable e.g. `int i = 0;` outside your `while` loop. Then,

Replace

```
salary = new SalariedEmployee(name1, id1, salariedemployee);
```

with

```
person[i++] = new SalariedEmployee(name1, id1, salariedemployee);
```

and

```
hoem = new HourEmployee(name2, id2, houremployee, hour);
```

with

```
person[i++] = new HourEmployee(name2, id2, houremployee, hour);
```

Finally, iterate the `Person[]` in `case 3:` e.g. as follows:

```
for(int j = 0; j < i; j++){
    System.out.println(person[j])
}
```

**Note:** Make sure to change the `while (flag)` to `while(flag && i < 100)` to avoid `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.